# Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available

Tags: macos, safari, google, web-browser, certificate

[image]

I am not sure what happened… My internet was working fine all day, so I do not know what would cause this message and notice my browser is currently not recognized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Don’t worry about it.**

The snippets of text you see in search results are what the webpage responded when the webcrawler was indexing it. Most of the time those error messages aren’t relevant to you at all.

In this case it’s not saying your browser isn’t recognized, but rather that the GoogleBot couldn’t play that YouTube video.

In other words, you’re fine. If you can play that video, then that’s all you need to worry about.

Comment: Hilarious that a Google crawler doesn't have a way to handle this behaviour from Youtube, Google's own service. Great snippets. (Of course, while searching for videos, one normally sees the video description as intended. I wonder what went wrong with the crawling here.)

Comment: So it is not because I was looking up homework video instructions.....

Comment: No, has nothing to do with that.